# Chosen JS does not send POST data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using [Chosen JS](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin in order to make my select boxes cooler and prettier; however, something's not quite right when sending this data via POST to PHP. Note, I'm also using codeigniter.

This is my html:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="multiple[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Something</option>
    <option value="2">Something</option>
    <option value="3">Something</option>
    <option value="4">Something</option>
</select>
```

This is my JS:

```
$('#mySelect').chosen({
    max_selected_options: 4,
    place_holder_text_multiple: "Pick your poison(s)"
});
```

Finally, my CodeIgniter model in which I catch the data sent by the form and insert it to the database.

```
// I want them to be introduced in the column of the database all together,
// separated by commas. 
$string = implode(",", $this->input->post('multiple'));
```

However, this only gets the first value introduced by the user.

Like, if him/her picked `"1, 4, 5"`,

it only gets `"1"`.

Is there something that I missed? Thank you beforehand.

**UPDATE** I also checked chrome's console in order to check if the data was being sent. This is what I got. I don't have enough reputation to post the image, but here's the link.

[My Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9Vv.png)

Comment: Check the browser console to see whether the data is sent correctly or not.

Comment: @SelvarajMA I just did. Updating the question...

Comment: already tried `var_dump($this->input->post('multiple'));`? do you see something like: `[0] => 1, [1] => 4, [2] => 5`

Comment: I'm on it, I just don't know where to put it. Adding `echo var_dump(...)` in the model does not print it ( I don't think that's the correct place).

Comment: I seem to remember having this exact problem many years ago with CI but I cannot remember how I solved it :( You could try do a `var_dump($_POST['multiple']); to make sure the values are being correctly received by CI. If they are then it is a problem with the CI input class.

Comment: do you mean your controller by model , if so you need to update your post cause it got me confused

Comment: are you using ajax post ? i had similar problem yesterday and solved it

Comment: @karanthakkar, could you give me an example, please? If you could explain it as an answear, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Try casting it to array

```
$string = implode(",", (array) $this->input->post('multiple'));
```

or cycle the array and append the values to a string

```
$msg = "";
foreach($this->input->post('multiple') as $key=>$val){
     $msg = $msg . "," . $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this what  did for it to submit my data to my DB

```
<div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <label>Chosen Multi Select with search</label>
    <select data-placeholder="Select Countries..." name = "countries[]" class="chosen_select form-control" tabindex="2" multiple="">
      <option value="1">Republic of Biafra</option>
      <option value="2">Arewa Republic</option>
      <option value="3">Oduduwa Republic</option>
      <option value="4">Abiriba</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Then for my controller, I try to check if the submitted input field name countries[] has values just as below then I submit to the database through my model:

```
if ( $this->input->post() ){

  $data = $this->input->post('countries');
  print_r($data);
  $this->load->model->('country);
  $this->country->add($data);
}
```

When I selected the Republic of Biafra, Abiriba and Oduduwa Republic my output became

```
Array
(
    [0] => Republic of Biafra
    [1] => Abiriba
    [2] => Oduduwa Republic
)
```

Since the submitted field is in the array then I loop my data in the country model in order to the array into a single string like this:

```
class Country {

  public function add ($data = ""){

     if (isset($data) && !empty($data)){
         // print_r($data);
         $str = '';
         foreach ($data as $value) {
             $str .= $value;
             $str .= ', '; // add separator between sub-arrays
         }
         $str = rtrim($str, ', '); // remove last separator
                print_r($str); // print to see output of what we just did
         // Here you can countinue your database command
     }
  }
}
```

The output of `print_r()` function is:

```
"1, 4, 3"
```

I hope this helped you